# Codeigniter: passing data to another view

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Ok, so this question may be very simple and I'm just missing something basic but here goes. My website I'm currently building is developed in Codeigniter. It's a site for exercises.

Now one of my functions (biceps) calls a model (model_get) that grabs data from my database and then passes it into a view (content_biceps.php)

So to try and explain this best as possible here is my controller model and view for this.

Controller function:

```
    public function biceps(){

        if($this->session->userdata("is_logged_in")){

            $this->load->model("model_get");
            $data["results"] = $this->model_get->getExercises("1");

            $this->load->view("site_header");
            $this->load->view("site_nav");
            $this->load->view("site_sidebar");
            $this->load->view("content_biceps", $data);
            $this->load->view("site_footer");
        }   else {
            redirect ("site/restricted");
        }
    }
```

Model function get_data:

```
    function getData($page){
        $query = $this->db->get_where("pagedata", array("page" => $page));
        return $query->result();
    }
```

View content_biceps:

```
foreach($results as $row){

    echo '<div class="item">
            <h2>'.$row->name.'</h2>
            <img src="'.$row->image.'" alt="'.$row->name.'" />';

    $e_id = $row->e_id;
    echo $e_id;

    echo form_submit('exercise_submit', 'view');
    echo '</div>';
    echo form_close();
}
```

Now this view works great, it grabs the data i need such as the name, image and e_id for each exercise and displays them all.

If you notice the submit button  named 'view'. If you can imagine all of these exercises displayed on one page. They all have a unique e_id. I want it so that when i click the view button on a certain exercise, i am taken to a page view such as 'exercise_view' where i can use the e_id to grab the data for that particular exercise. At the moment I dont know how to take the e_id when i click view and use it in another page.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add an input with the e_id you want, for example

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="e_id" value="{$e_id}" />
    <input type="submit" name="view" />
</div>
```

then in controller, you can get the e_id

```
$e_id = $this->input->post('e_id');
```

Comment: Ok, so my form now looks like this:

    echo form_open('site/exercise_validation');

    $e_id = $row->e_id;
    echo $e_id;
    form_hidden('e_id', $e_id);
    echo form_submit('exercise_submit', 'view');
    echo '</div>';
    echo form_close();

Comment: My exercise_validation controller looks like this:

        public function exercise_validation(){

            $e_id = $this->input->post('e_id');

            $this->load->view("site_header");
            $this->load->view("site_nav");
            $this->load->view("site_sidebar");
            $this->load->view("content_exercise_view", $e_id);
            $this->load->view("site_footer");

        }

And my content_exercise_view looks like this:

    <?php

    echo $e_id;

    ?>

I'm getting an unidentified e_id error.

where am i going wrong?

Comment: $data['e_id'] = $e_id;$this->load->view('content_exercise_view', $data);

Comment: where has $data come from? what have you substituted it for?